# Shell context menu registry extension doesn't work when default program is other than Notepad

Tags: windows-10, shell, context-menu

I'm trying to add a "Tail" entry to the shell context menu for `.txt` files, but whatever I do the option just *does not appear*.

My `.reg` file looks like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\Tail]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\Tail\command]
@="tail.exe -f \"%1\""
```

It worked fine in Windows 7. Has this feature been disabled in Windows 10 (64-bit)?

How to make it work again?

**==EDIT==**

Some additional findings:

The default **Open** action is associated with **Notepad++**.

If I choose the built-in *Notepad* application as the default *Open* action, then my "Tail" menu item shows up. But as soon as I choose *Notepad++* or *any other app* as the default *Open* action, my custom context menu item disappears.

Comment: The feature is not disabled. Which program have you set as the default for opening `.txt` files?

Comment: Notepad++ is my default Open program for `.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This registry setting should help.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad++.exe\shell\Tail\command]
@="tail.exe -f \"%1\""
```

Only downside is that "Tail" would show up for every file type associated with Notepad++. If you don't want that, post back so that I can make another REG file that applies only for .txt files.

Comment: Thanks! I can live with the "downside". But just out of curiosity was wondering how to make it apply only to `.txt` files.

Comment: To apply the setting for .txt file (per-file type basis), implement the menu here:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.txt`